# LaunchAgents: Launch App as root

Tags: macos, kiosk, launchctl

I'm doing a kiosk app for osx. there was a previous version of this app working on OSX 10.8, but the computers got updated and now the app isn't working properly. i need to avoid user can kill the process. so, lets call the main app as A. "A" should be able to run from any user as root to avoid being killed by users. I'm using a LaunchAgent to launch it automatically when the user login. there's no problem running A as a root. as Launchctl can't run A propertly as root. and i can't run A as a Daemon because it need to be interative, I'm using a second program called "B", "B" does a system call to "A" as a root user and then calls "exit" to avoid "A" being killed when "B" dies. that works if i run B directly from terminal, but when Launchctl runs B and it dies, A dies too. i dont know how to solve it, how to keep "A" running as root even when "B" ends.

this is how B is calling A:

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

    system("sudo /Path/to/A & exit;");

}
system("sleep 15"); // trick that tell launchctl that everything was ok
return 0;
}
```